# lexical scoping in javascript not showing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone explain me that why dosent this code show error when we have redeclared let x=5 in this code? It should show error due to lexical scoping .

```
  function demoFunction() {
    let x = 10; 
  
    function demo() {
      let y = 20; 
      let x=5;
      console.log(x); 
      console.log(y); 
    }
    console.log(x); 
    demo();
  }
  
  demoFunction();
```

Can anyone explain me that why dosent this code show error when we have redeclared let x=5 in this code? It should show error due to lexical scoping .

Comment: You redeclared it inside a different function.

Comment: For the same reason why `function demoFunction() { let x=0; if(true) {let x=2; console.log(x);} console.log(x);}` does not result in an error.

Comment: Because of block scoped nature of different functions and two separate execution contexts, this thing is happening.

Comment: this is shadowing, not redeclaration. The difference being that it's in a new scope, that of the function `demo`.

Comment: Did you read up on the scoping rules for `let`? Both `let` and `const` are block scoped (with the legacy `var` being function scoped, which is why we don't use it anymore). So you can shadow any `let` or `const` variable with a new variable that has the same name, as long as it's in a new (nested) block.

Answer (score 2):

You can see this is acceptable from the first example in [MDN's documentation for let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Further down you can see this quote:

> let declarations cannot be redeclared by any other declaration in the same scope.

The key being "same scope".

From [MDN's definition of scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope):

> JavaScript has the following kinds of scopes:
>
> Global scope: The default scope for all code running in script mode.
>
> Module scope: The scope for code running in module mode.
>
> Function scope: The scope created with a function.
>
> In addition, variables declared with let or const can belong to an additional scope:
>
> Block scope: The scope created with a pair of curly braces (a block).

Both declarations of `x` in your example are in two different function scopes, so this is acceptable.

---

Note that unlike `var`, `let` will create an entirely new variable every time. `var` only creates new variables within new *function scopes* (`var` is essentially legacy code to support old apps - don't use it).

You can also reference variables that are *not* in the same scope, but *are* in an enclosing scope. The chain of enclosing scopes is referred to as a scope chain. When referencing `x`, the interpreter will take the first `x` it finds in the scope chain.

```js
// Global scope (0)
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let z = 0;
{ // Block scope (1) start
  let y = 1;
  let z = 1;
  { // Block scope (2) start
    let z = 2;
    console.log(`x is in scope ${x}`); // 0
    console.log(`y is in scope ${y}`); // 1
    console.log(`z is in scope ${z}`); // 2
  } // Block scope (2) end
  console.log(`x is in scope ${x}`); // 0
  console.log(`y is in scope ${y}`); // 1
  console.log(`z is in scope ${z}`); // 1
} // Block scope (1) end
console.log(`x is in scope ${x}`); // 0
console.log(`y is in scope ${y}`); // 0
console.log(`z is in scope ${z}`); // 0
```

In that snippet, there are 6 distinct variables (one `x`, two `y`s and three `z`s). Which variable gets referenced depends on which scope I am doing the referencing. The interpreter will take the closest one in the scope chain.

Comment: so var dosent create an entirely different variable?

Comment: Not if you're only using blocks. If you use _functions_ then `var` creates a new variable, scoped to the entire function (meaning that at runtime, the first thing the function does is create that variable, no matter where in the function you declared it. It gets hoisted), but we don't use `var` anymore exactly because of this: it doesn't behave like variable declaration is expected to behave if you come to JS from pretty much _any_ other language. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

From ES6 (in 2015), JavaScript introduced new features from which `let` and `const` keywords are new additions.

Now before `let` and `const` we had `var` keyword. Even if you had used `var` here it would have been fine, since it is clearly in its own scope.

In your code below:

```
  function demoFunction() {
    let x = 10; 
  
    function demo() {
      let y = 20; 
      let x=5;
      console.log(x); 
      console.log(y); 
    }
    console.log(x); 
    demo();
  }
  
  demoFunction();
```

You have used a `demo()` function inside the `demoFunction()`, Why would you expect it throw error. If you have learned the concept of execution block. Then you know that each function once called has it's own **Execution context** which contains the variable set defined inside it. So, the variable x declared inside the `demo()` function has its own Execution Context and its own scope. As function is invoked the set of variables can be accessed being in that scope and and function returns, the variables are destroyed. So, no question of *outer variable x* ever knowing there was some other variables inside other function.

Answer (score -1):

You're not getting any sort of lexical scoping error because variables declared with let and const keywords are block-scoped (In strict mode). Since functions are also block-scoped, variables declared within certain block are accessible within that function. But, every function has its own separate execution context which gets called in a call stack internally one by one.
These two variables have two different scope and two different execution contexts, that's why it's not showing any sort of error.

```
function demoFunction() {
    // Variables declared here is accessible within demoFunction scope.
    let x = 10; 
  
    function demo() {
      let y = 20; 
      // This variable here is accessible within demo scope.
      let x=5;
      console.log(x); 
      console.log(y); 
    }
    console.log(x); 
    demo();
  }
  
  demoFunction();
```

Comment: so why does the x value gets changed for outer scope also in this.                  function demoFunction() {
    var x = 10;
    if(true){
      let y = 20; 
   var x=5;
      console.log(x); 
      console.log(y); 
    }
    console.log(x); 
  }
  
  demoFunction();

Comment: Two catches are here
1. You're using var keyword to declare x. variables declared with var x isn't a block scoped but closest functional scope. Not to mention, it also creates a whole new property or variable on global scope object. Because of this property, it overrides the previous value.
2. Here's only one execution context, so every operation is happening in a single environment.

Comment: One advice, though. Do not use var keyword to declare variables in JavaScript or TypeScript. Always use let/const.